# Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonString is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to access the JSON from the Spring boot controller, from my external static Js file. It is giving an error as *Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonString is not defined*. Below are the relevant code snippets:

@controller:-

```
@RequestMapping("/a")
public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView model){
    List<Post> posts = postService.getAllPost();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(posts);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    model.addObject("jsonString" ,jsonString);
    model.setViewName("index.html");
    return model;
}
```

script.js:-

```
var element = JSON.parse(`${jsonString}`);
console.log(element)
```

I want to access the list of posts from script.js. Please guide how to achieve this task or a better way of doing it.

Comment: How are you defining `jsonString` in your **script.js**

Comment: The jsonString you added to the model is available on the server side eg in JSP, but js is executing on client - there's not really enough information to go on, but does that help?

Comment: @Barmar Why was the JS tag removed when there is very clearly JS?

Comment: @Gunnarhawk Sorry, I didn't see the little JS at the end.

Comment: @Gunnarhawk I am using Spring boot's MVP, jsonString is supposed to come directly from ModelAndView object of spring, it certainly is applicable in JSP but I am struggling to implement it on plain external javascript. The answer to your question could be the answer to mine.

Comment: @Kinglish I am using Spring framework for backend and javascript in the frontend, the main problem is the combination of both Java and Javascript.

Comment: I believe your error is that `jsonString` is not being defined in your JS. I have not used **spring** before, but are you calling your model somewhere in the script so that it knows what to use? The front end and back end of any program are normally two separate entities